# How to remove quotation marks from a generic InputField

Tags: inputfield

I need to use an InputField with a generic dynamic variable (not restricted to be Number or String or whatsever) and I don't want to see the quotation marks in the case the input is a string. 
Here is an example

```
z="";
InputField[Dynamic[z]]
```

I know the Cell's option ShowStringCharacter but here doesn't work, for instance see

```
z = "";
Panel[Column[{Style[InputField[Dynamic[z]], 
    ShowStringCharacters -> False], Spacer[5], 
   Row[{"This is the value of variable z", Spacer[5], Dynamic[z]}]}]]
```

and this one

```
z = "";
ExpressionCell[
 Panel[Column[{Style[InputField[Dynamic[z]], 
     ShowStringCharacters -> False], Spacer[5], 
    Row[{"This is the value of variable z", Spacer[5], 
      Dynamic[z]}]}]], ShowStringCharacters -> False]
```

Any suggestion?
Thanks in advace,
Roberto

Comment: Then how can the `InputField` distinguish what head has the input e.g. `123 a`, should it be `"123 a"` or `123 a`?

Comment: @Kuba, I know, and indeed I think the InputField behavior is correct, but ShowStringCharacter is just for that, I mean just for visualization. If you do z = "test"; ExpressionCell[z, "Text", ShowStringCharacters -> False] the quotation marks are not printed, however z is still a string.

Comment: but this is not an `Input` type `Cell`, try to edit it.

Comment: You are right, this is a different type of cell, the ExpressionCell generates a Cell with the value of the variable z and not the variable itself inside a Dynamic. Moreover, it uses InterpretationBox exactly to have the visualization different from the expression, that's the trick. And I guess this is not replicable inside a Dynamic object. Thanks anyhow.

Comment: It's not a problem of `Dynamic`, cell types or a possbilities of MMA. The problem is that the behaviour you need is, as I showed earlier, ambigious. Clarify how *Mathematica* has to know when you enter a string or not and we can work on this.

Comment: yes, this is the key point. InputField has to use (and show) quotation marks to distinguish the type of input. Thanks for that deep comments, they help me to close the question.

Answer (score 2):

May be this is what you are looking for. Calling `Style` before calling `InputField`, rather than after, seems to work.

```
z = "fox";
Panel[
  Column[{
    InputField[Style[Dynamic[z], ShowStringCharacters -> False]], 
    Spacer[5], 
    Row[{"This is the value of variable z: ", Spacer[5], Dynamic[z]
  }]}]]
```

[image: panel.png]